# Listbox control in a window application

Tags: c#, windows

I have a listbox control and I have to display a selected item in the listbox.

Here is code I have so far:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   textBox1.Clear();
   foreach (object selectedItem in listBox1.SelectedItems)
   {
      textBox1.AppendText(selectedItem.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
   }
}
```

But it is giving me an error at `foreach`.

Comment: if your doing a appendtext after a clear you can better use textBox.Text

Comment: What error is it giving?

Comment: If you add 4 spaces in front of each code line then it will be much easier to read (or use the built-in function, "010101" icon, keyboard shortcut Ctrl+K).

Comment: What kind of error do you receive ?

Comment: What is your platform? WPF? Winforms ASP.NET? .NET version?

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer the question, please post a sample of the error message you receive

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The code you posted does not crash for me.  The comment on this answer is correct, SelectedItems is empty, but not null, if no item is selected.  Did you leave out some of the code to simplify things?

Check whether listBox1.SelectedItems is null first.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    textBox1.Clear(); 

    if (listBox1.SelectedItems != null)
    {
        foreach (object selectedItem in listBox1.SelectedItems) 
        { 
            textBox1.AppendText(selectedItem.ToString() + Environment.NewLine); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: `SelectedItems` is never null, you would probably want to check the count instead: `if (listBox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)`

Comment: I stand corrected.  Just tested the code and it does not crash as posted.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
foreach(object o in this.listBox1.SelectedItems) 
{ 
  aa.Add(selectedItem);
}
```

Comment: How is that any different compared to the code of the topicstarter (besides the redundant use of 'this' ) ?

Comment: Where does `selectedItem` come from if your loop is using a variable `o`?

Comment: I think that for reasons unknown to me, you do not run your event. 
Yes, I added this